# Is there any way to get out of a frozen game without going to command line?

Tags: games, freeze

It would be pretty simple, I hit the super key and it brings up the launcher over my frozen game. But it opens it up to search for an application. Alt-f1 should bring a keyboard controlled launcher, that would work, but it won't open in game. Only super key opens the launcher while in a game, but it doesn't open it up in a way to close it.

I know I could always pgrep and kill, but it would be nice just to be able to open up the launcher in game and kill it from there. Is there any way to bring up the keyboard controlled launcher when in a frozen game?

[edit]
Xkill is usually great but it doesn't exactly work when your in a game that's frozen. Hitting super may or may not open the launcher. Maybe I can bind a new hotkey to launch xkill...

Answer (score 3):

`xkill` is a program which allows you to kill applications with your mouse.

- press the Super key
- type `xkill`, Enter
- the cursor changes to a skull, clicking anywhere in the game's window should terminate it.